# How to handle spring and hibernate exceptions

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Can anyone give me an example how to catch and represent spring and hibernate in a meaningful way?

Assume if during the registration, a customer wish to use his creating name which is already exist in the table, I should display a friendly message such as "the login name is already exist blah blah blah".

I am new to Web application and I couldn't really understand how to handle kind of violation. I read the spring doc and hibernate doc as well as do some research on google. But it is so hard to understand without visualize a good tutorial/example. Right now every method in my dao and service is repeating surrounded with try and catch block which I think it looks so redundant.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You execute a query to test if the name already exists, and if it does, you throw a NameAlreadyExistsException (for example). If it does not, you proceed with the registration.

Comment: @Terry dang also you can refer [this](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/07/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc.html) for more on `Spring Exception handling`.